# Can I ask a question about the use of 'null' and 'Maybe' types?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a question that I was going to post on Software Engineering, but I suddenly stumbled upon this site, and now I'm wondering if the question would be on-topic here.

There's a draft available [here](https://gist.github.com/stijnherreman/206ec18fb01eb719e2870c1a4847e1b2), but here's a summary:

> I'm now wondering if it makes sense to have both the concept of *null* and *Maybe*, to represent *unknown* and *nothing* respectively. Is this the three-valued logic I read about, or does it have another name? Or is the intended way to nest a Maybe in a Maybe?

Looking at your questions, they all seem to be a lot more theoretical than my question, so I think it's off-topic, but figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: This seems to be on topic here, I'm just not sure about which tags to use, maybe `programming-languages` + some more specific tag.

Comment: This is not at all an answer to your question, but note that `Maybe` is a _type constructor_, not a type unto itself; it is sometimes important to understand this difference. (In Haskell-speak, its kind is `* -> *`, not just `*`.)

Comment: @wchargin Thanks for your input. The question was posted [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68052/does-it-make-sense-to-have-both-the-concept-of-null-and-maybe) fyi :)

Comment: That question turned out to prompt very interesting answers, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We do have the [programming-languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) and [language-design](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design) tags. As long as your questions fall into these categories and are (mostly) language-agnostic they are very welcome!